# Using stl algorithms in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why can't I use STL algorithms in threads like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::thread t(std::max, 5, 6);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This has the compiler error::

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int)’
     std::thread t(std::max, 5, 6);
```

I tried to explicitly specify `std::max<int>` to avoid the uncertainty of which `max`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::thread t(std::max<int>, 5, 6);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int)’
     std::thread t(std::max<int>, 5, 6);
note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’
     std::thread t(std::max<int>, 5, 6);
note: candidate: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
note: candidate: std::thread::thread()
thread() noexcept = default;
note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

Comment: First one is probably uncertainty over which `max`. Second one looks OK other than a missing semicolon.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry, the second really works. How can i fix first example? I try: thread t(max<int>, 5, 6); , but it doesn't work.

Comment: `max<int>` is still not specific enough. You would need something like `(int const&(*)(int const&,int const&))std::max` to clarify which max you mean.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, thx, it works.

Comment: @Marc Son of a gun. I was poking at that (with a `using` statement) and hour ago and I couldn't get it to work because I left out the `const` in the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [several overloads of `std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), which is why you get your error. Using `std::max<int>` doesn't disambiguate it, since there are still overloads that match `std::max<int>`:

```
template< class T >
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );

template< class T >
constexpr T max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
```

There are 2 easy options:

1. Disambiguate by casting to the correct function type:

   ```
   std::thread t(static_cast<const int&(*)(const int&, const int&)>(std::max), 5, 6);
   ```

   This is easy to get wrong, and forces you to figure out the actual function signature you want, rather than just how you want it to behave.
2. Make a lambda function:

   ```
   std::thread t([](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); }, 5, 6);
   ```

I strongly recommend using the lambda function, as you get to express exactly how you expect the function to behave. Furthermore, lambdas play well with default arguments.